# Double wall AC socket with load on one side and power supply

Tags: power-supply, socket

I have on AC socket a load wire on the right side.

I want to connect a power supply with separated load and neutral inputs.

How to handle the case when a plug will be put on the top, next on the bottom of a socket? The load wire will change the place and the power supply will be damaged?

Power supply
https://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=LRS-350

Sockets:

[image]

Plug:

[image]

Comment: Their is no problem as the orientation is inverted on these outlets. And not as you have circled.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are asking, so I am afraid of giving an answer, and you must understand that you are dealing with 240V mains AC voltage which is dangerous and deadly, so don't do anything unless you fully understand what you are doing. If this is about live and neutral swapping places, well that is what is common on German Schuko plugs. You seem to have the French plug.

Comment: Did you test the sockets to see which pin is live and which is neutral? I think you might find that there are diagonal cross-connections between the two sockets.

Comment: why????????????

Comment: It is almost NEVER the case that live & neutral can not be switched, and that power supply certainly won't care either.    The thing is, although there is a "standard" way to wire an outlet, miswired outlets are FAR more common than you might think, so products have to be designed with the assumption that live & neutral are not necessarily what you expect and DEFINITELY there can not be a safety hazard if they were flipped.   This is why you'll very often find two fuses in European products, one on live, one on neutral.

Comment: So, my sockets are incorrectly connected. @KyleB, I have to make sure and find that in docs that the power supply would survive an 'accidental' flip.

Comment: I don't know.  I don't have a multimeter to check them.  I also don't know which pin is which in your country.  All I meant is across your country (any country really), there WILL be miswired boxes, and electrical products have to be tolerant of it.

Comment: I would be willing to say 99.999999% likely that power supply will not care which wire is which.

Comment: @LancerX what is `'accidental' flip` ... it is totally unclear what problem you are describing

Comment: @Kyle B, look at the link of mean well power supply I put in the post or on that one. It has two inputs: L and N. So it cares. But I understand that you mean that it will not blow up with wrong connection. https://www.ebay.com/itm/MEAN-WELL-LRS-350-24-Switching-Power-Supply-350W-24V-14-6A-/352677250814

Comment: To be clear, I checked which one is load, which neutral with probe tester. And it's like I marked on the picture. Otherwise my post would have no sense. :P

Comment: @user253751: The reason I asked is that if the country has polarised sockets (that only go in one way) then there may be a standard. Note that the earth pin is not in the centre of the circle. It appears that the sockets are connected vertically at the back so my question has been answered. I live in Ireland where we use British Standard 13A plugs/sockets. These are fused internally and there is a most definite and prescribed live and neutral orientation. The sockets in the photo will take the flat 2-pin plugs in either orientation.

Comment: @LancerX ... In your case, I do not think it 'just won't work'... I really do mean "it won't care".   They mark them because they have to mark them with SOMETHING.  But if you flip the wires, it will still work.     Here's a picture of a "typical" power supply input.   You will quickly notice it's symmetrical.   http://www.marcspages.co.uk/pq/3331.gif

Comment: @Transistor Not you. WHY?????????? does LancerX want to use the live pin from one socket and the neutral pin from a different socket? Why not just use one socket?????

Answer (score 0):

You can check with tester is it connected as you circled. And check is one of the wires in plug goes to the PSU shield. Anyway single power supply will not be damaged. Note that most of the AC sockets has no polarity. But if you have 2 non-isolated PSU and want to use them in parallel, there are some variants available in case all systems are bad-engineered.